# Does the feat Southern Magician still have as a prerequisite being a Mulan human?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

A friend said that the Mulan human prerequisite for the *Races of Faerûn* feat Southern Magician was changed at some point after the *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* revision, but I can't find anything changing the feat Southern Magician. Were any changes made to the feat made by another source?

If no changes were made to the feat Southern Magician, is there a way to take this feat without being a Mulan human?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The feat Southern Magician has remained unchanged since its initial publication

So far as I can tell, while many feats from *Races* were updated by the *Player's Guide to Faerûn*, not so the feat Southern Magician (*Races of Faerûn* 168). The feat *still* has being a Mulan human as a prerequisite, and I am unaware of any effect—beyond GM fiat—that allows a creature to count as a creature possessing a different *D&D 3.5*-style *ethnicity* (as defined on *PG* 10).

However, because the feat Southern Magician doesn't have the type regional, it's available to any human of Mulan ethnicity, and while such Mulan humans are most common to the regions of Altumbel, Chessenta, Mulhorand, Thay, and Unther, they could pop up anywhere on Faerûn with a complicated enough background.

An argument can be made that the feat's description *should* allow *any* creature to take the feat Southern Magician if the creature possesses the correct background ("Your magical studies in Mulan lands have taught you spellcasting techniques unknown in the north that blur the line between arcane and divine magic"), but an equally strong counterargument could be made that the Mulan human prerequisite makes it clear that there's something unique to being a Mulan human that's required to realize the feat's benefit. Good luck.